# JavaScript destructuring in reduce() method not working with Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, destructuring

I use the JavaScript [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to count how many entries have the same values.

If I use the code with the Firefox 52 browser everything works fine. But if I use the code in Internet Explorer 11, the debugger told me, that there is an error in the script:

```js
const data = [{
    'jahr': '2017',
    'monat': '3'
  },
  {
    'jahr': '2017',
    'monat': '3'
  },
  {
    'jahr': '2017',
    'monat': '4'
  }
];

map = new Map,
  ergebnisMonat = data.reduce((r, {
    jahr,
    monat
  }) => {
    var datum = [monat, jahr].join('-');
    if (!map.has(datum)) {
      map.set(datum, {
        datum,
        anzahl: 0
      });
      r.push(map.get(datum));
    }
    map.get(datum).anzahl++;
    return r;
  }, []);

console.log(ergebnisMonat);
```

> SCRIPT1003: ':' expected

The debugger told me that the ":" is expected here:

```
ergebnisMonat = data.reduce((r, {
        jahr**here ERROR**,
        monat
```

The `reduce()` method is compatible with IE since version 9. So I don’t know why it works in Firefox and not in IE 11. Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its destructor and not reduce that is not supported

Comment: I think the unsupported part is the object destructuring and arrow function.

Comment: Yep, destructuring not supported: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#ie11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the **[destructuring docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**, its not at all supported in IE and hence

```
data.reduce((r, {
    jahr,
    monat
  })
```

is not supported, Also **[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** don't have support in IE, so you need to use the conventional function definition

```
ergebnisMonat = data.reduce(function(r, obj){
    var datum = [obj.monat, obj.jahr].join('-');
    if (!map.has(datum)) {
      map.set(datum, {
        datum,
        anzahl: 0
      });
      r.push(map.get(datum));
    }
    map.get(datum).anzahl++;
    return r;
  }, []);
```

Comment: Now the debugger says that there is the same error here:`map.set(datum, {
        datum**ERROR**,
        anzahl: 0`

Comment: so you need `map.set(datum, {
        datum: datum,
        anzahl: 0
      });`

Comment: Thank you so much!